# Compare List<T> with object T

Tags: c#, comparison

I have an empty list with let's say students. Before I insert a student in the list, I want to check if there is already one with the same ID.

Note that this is pseudo code!

```
class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // ID is NOT unique
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<Student> AddStudentsToList()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

        foreach (Student student in source) // source is the place where the information comes from(text file, DB, etc.)
        {
            if (CompareStudents(students, student)) // Here's the place where I have to check if student with the current ID already exists in the list students(List<Student>)
            {
                students.Add(new Student(student));
            }
        }
        return students;
    }

    private bool CompareStudents(List<Student> students, Student s) // Going through the whole list every time can't be the best solution, I think
    {
        bool duplicate = false;
        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            if (student.ID == s.ID)
            {
                duplicate = true;
            }
        }

        return duplicate;
    }
}
```

Can I(and how) do this more efficiently?

NOTE: I need to keep track of duplicates so Dictionary doesn't help at all.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: It doesn't help in this case. I want to know whether student is a duplicate or not.

Comment: Your code won't do anything as is.  If the student is a duplicate you add him to the list.  But the list is empty at the beginning, so you will never find a duplicate... the list will always be empty.

Comment: The dictionary *ContainsKey* lets you know if the student exists.

Comment: What behaviour do you want if a duplicate ID is found?

Comment: Add it to another list called duplicates, for example.

Comment: "for example" is too vague to give me confidence in the question. Take a step back, and decide what it is you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void AddStudentsToList()
{
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>();

    foreach (Student student in source)
    {
        if (!ids.Add(student.ID))
        {
            students.Add(new Student(student));
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, you probably want to return `students` from your method or use some field/property instead of local variable to store list of students, otherwise method is pointless.

Comment: @JeanHominal You're right, I missed the fact that there is nothing like *initial list of students*. Changed `Contains` to `Add` and used parameterless constructor.

Comment: I am not going to blame you for missing such a thing - I mean, the question's code lacks the context of use (where is `source` defined, and what type does it have? Why does the `AddStudentsToList` method have neither an observable side-effect, nor a return value?)

Comment: That's why I said it's pseudo code. Sorry if I messed up the code and the question. I've added return value.

Answer (score 0):

Break the loop after you found a duplicate:

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
     if (student.ID == s.ID)
     {
         duplicate = true;
         break;
     }
}
```

You can do the same thing using `Enumerable.Any` method:

```
return students.Any(student => student.ID == s.ID);
```

If you want more efficient solution, you can use a `HashSet`

```
return new HashSet<Student>(students).Count == students.Count;
```

This also requires overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for your class like below:

```
class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.ID.Equals(((Student)obj).ID);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to change your if statement to:

```
if (!CompareStudents(students, student))
```

Your method returns *true* if there is a duplicate so you need to use negation operator because you want to perform adding only when `CompareStudents` return *false*.

Comment: OP asks for efficient solutions, so `HashSet` is not "also an alternative" - it should be the recommended solution here.

Comment: The HashSet solution in this answer is good only if students with the same ID are the same instance.  Otherwise it should be a HashSet of the students' IDs.

Comment: @Selman22 `this.ID.Equals(((Student)obj).ID);` this will throw if `Student` will be compared with another class - in general not recommended implementation of `Equals`.

Comment: @BartoszKP I know, I have ignored the null check because I assume the OP will never call the equals method on Student to compare different type with the current instance.I'm just too lazy ofcourse using the `as` operator is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what needs to be done with the object afterwards, this is generally a prime example for when a `HashTable` is the best choice of collection object - not a `List`. If you need to do lookups by ID later, then a `Dictionary` collection is likely the best choice.

Knowing when to choose the correct collection can really make your code much easier. More info: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using .Net 3.5 or higher, use a [generic HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of a list, and [implement your own equals method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that compares the ID, as well as the getHashcode method.

The add method on the HashSet will return false if the element is already present.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but only provided that you implement [`IEqualityComparer<Student>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or make `Student` comparable:

```
class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // ID is NOT unique
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<Student> AddStudentsToList()
    {
        var students = source.Distinct().ToList();

        return students;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Student other)
    {
        var otherStudent = other as Student;

        if (otherStudent == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return otherStudent.ID == this.ID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*OK, complete rewrite...*

Given a list of student data from an arbitrary source - Database, flat file, etc - you can use LINQ queries or extensions to rearrange the list in a number of interesting ways.

For instance:

```
public class LoadedStudent
{
    public int ID;
    public Student Primary;
    public Student[] Duplicates;
}

public List<LoadedStudent> LoadStudents(IEnumerable<Student> source)
{
    var query = 
        from s in students
        group s by s.ID into grp
        let primary = grp.First()
        select new LoadedStudent 
        { 
            ID = primary.ID,
            Primary = primary,
            Duplicates = grp.Skip(1).ToArray()
        };

    return Query.ToList();
}
```

From the above you get a list of all loaded students grouped together by `ID`, with one selected as the primary and the remainder dropped into an array.  Converting the import list into `List<Student>` is as simple as:

```
List<LoadedStudent> loadedstudents = LoadStudents(source);
List<Student> students = loadedstudents.Select(ls => ls.Primary).ToList();
```

You can do additional processing on either of the lists to determine who has duplicates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Student> lstNumbers = new List<Student>();
        Student studentInstance = new Student();
        studentInstance.ID=1;
        studentInstance.Name="Student1";
        studentInstance.Age = 55;
        Student testStudent = lstNumbers.Find(p => p.ID == studentInstance.ID);
        if (testStudent == null)
        {
            lstNumbers.Add(studentInstance);
        }
```

You can either use extension methods like above code or use LINQ query to perform the same.

Comment: Using `Find` to test for existence is a little off.  That's what the `Any` extension is for: `if (!lstNumbers.Any(p => p.ID == studentInstance.ID)) { lstNumbers.Add(studentInstance); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can shorter your code buy check ID with Linq, remove ! in if() statement if you only want add duplicate student in to list. but as your list was empty initially you will not add any student into there as you wouldn't find any duplicated student.

```
public void AddStudentsToList()
{
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

foreach (Student student in source)
{
    if (!students.where(s => s.ID == student.ID).any())
    {
        students.Add(new Student(student));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is definitely the way forward. Use `ContainsKey` to determine whether you already have one by a particular ID. If you don't then add the new one to the dictionary. If you do then store it in a list of duplicates.

```
class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
Dictionary<int, Student> students = new Dictionary<int, Student>();
List<Student> duplicates = new List<Student>();
private void ReadStudents(IEnumerable<Student> source)
{
    // source could contain the same student more than once
    foreach (Student student in source)
    {
        if (students.ContainsKey(student.ID))
            duplicates.Add(student);
        else
            students[student.ID] = student;
    }
}
public void Test()
{
    List<Student> input = new List<Student>() { 
        new Student { ID=1, Name="Adam", Age=18 },
        new Student { ID=2, Name="Bert", Age=18 },
        new Student { ID=3, Name="Charlie", Age=19 },
        new Student { ID=1, Name="Adam", Age=18 }, // duplicate
    };

    ReadStudents(input);
    // 'students' now contains the list with duplicates removed
    // 'duplicates' contains all the duplicates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement IEqualityComparer

```
class Equalitycompare<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    Func<T, T, bool> _equalsFunction;
    Func<T, int> _hashCodeFunction;

    public Equalitycompare( Func<T, T, bool> equalsFunction, Func<T, int> hashCodeFunction)
    {
        if (equalsFunction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (hashCodeFunction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

     _equalsFunction = equalsFunction;
     _hashCodeFunction = hashCodeFunction;
    }
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _equalsFunction(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _hashCodeFunction(obj);
    }
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    Student Student1 = new Student();
    Student1.ID = 1;
    Student Student2 = new Student();
    Student2.ID = 1;
    Student Student3 = new Student();
    Student3.ID = 3;
    var comparer = new Equalitycompare<Student>((x, y) => x.ID == y.ID, x =>           x.ID.GetHashCode());
   var students = new List<Student>{Student1,Student2,Student3};
   var uniquestudents = students.Distinct(comparer);
 }
```

Have a look at this very good article on http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LambdaEqualityComparer.aspx